# SOQL Request / data model

Tags: soql, query, data-model

This is my data model :
[image]

I would like to get list of Classes(*Class*) with class category *(Product_Category__c.Name)* ,price (*PricebookEntry.UnitPrice*) and some fieds of the Class.

What I've done :

```
Select  class__r.id , class__r.Product_Short_Description__c,class__r.Image_URL__c,class__r.Name
         from Class_Category_Relationship__c WHERE Class_Category__c =:categoryId
```

With this I get classes with its category but i don't know how to get price .

Comment: You need to create two separate queries based on your data model

Comment: ok thanks that what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best answer but it works

```
List<Class_Category_Relationship__c> classRel = [Select class__r.id , class__r.Product_Short_Description__c,class__r.Image_URL__c,class__r.Name from Class_Category_Relationship__c WHERE Class_Category__c =:categoryId];
Set<id> idProduct= new Set<id>();
for (Class_Category_Relationship__c c:classRel){
                idProduct.add(c.id);
            }

List<PricebookEntry> pbe=[Select UnitPrice, Product2.Name,Product2.id,Product2.Description FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2.id IN: idProduct ];
```